# Why doesn't Thor recognize my command line option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor

I am writing some rake tasks with Thor. In these thor tasks I am specifying some method options to make the command line more robust but the problem that I am running into is that thor is not recognizing my commands.

Here is an example task:

```
module ReverificationTask
  class Notifications < Thor
     option :bounce_threshold, :aliases => '-bt', :desc => 'Sets bounce rate', :required => true, :type => :numeric
     option :num_email, :aliases => '-e', :desc => 'Sets the amount of email', :required => true, :type => :numeric

     desc 'resend_to_soft_bounced_emails [BOUNCE_THRESHOLD] [NUM_EMAIL]'

     def resend_to_soft_bounced_emails(bounce_rate, amount_of_email)
        Reverification::Process.set_amazon_stat_settings(bounce_rate, amount_of_email)
        Reverification::Mailer.resend_soft_bounced_notifications
     end
  end
end
```

I have followed the Thor official web page on 'Options' [WhatisThor](http://whatisthor.com/) and when I run `thor help reverification_task:notifications:resend_to_soft_bounced_emails`

It correctly outputs what I would expect to see in the command line argument:

```
Usage:
thor reverification_task:notifications:resend_to_soft_bounced_emails [BOUNCE_THRESHOLD] [NUM_EMAIL] -bt, --bounce-threshold=N -e, --num-email=N

Options:
  -bt, --bounce-threshold=N  # Sets bounce rate
  -e, --num-email=N          # Sets the amount of email
```

When I execute `thor reverification_task:notifications:resend_to_soft_bounced_emails -bt 20 -e 2000` this is the response:

```
No value provided for required options '--bounce-threshold'
```

What is the problem here? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just mixed options with arguments. If you add arguments to your thor task definition, as you did in `def resend_to_soft_bounced_emails(bounce_rate, amount_of_email)`, you need to call them as command line arguments too:

```
thor reverification_task:notifications:resend_to_soft_bounced_emails 20 2000
```

But you rather wanted to use options (passed on the command line with `-` prefixes), so you should remove the arguments from your task definition and refer to the options using the `options` hash:

```
def resend_to_soft_bounced_emails
  Reverification::Process.set_amazon_stat_settings(options[:bounce_threshold], 
                                                   options[:num_email])
  Reverification::Mailer.resend_soft_bounced_notifications
end
```